# Show void * buffer content in Eclipse IDE debug

Tags: c, eclipse

I use Eclipse to develop small C application. I would like to see data at `void * buffer` pointer. Variables window shows only address of buffer variable. How to see data content at this address?

I'm using Linux OS and GCC as compiler.

Comment: Eclipse is just an IDE, not a compiler (it uses some external compiler & debugger). On which operating system and with which compiler and debugger are you working?

Comment: So you are probably using the `gdb` debugger. Read [the documentation of `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and how to [examine data](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Data.html) in it.

Comment: Can you show us you code of printing `buffer`?